# Matching a randomly generated String to input

Tags: java, if-statement

In Java

If you have generated a completely random letter e.g. "h" or "p" and you need to verify the user has entered "h" or "p" using Scanner, how would you verify they have done that and not entered something incorrect?

Comment: @jackjay so I've tried using an if statement for a String that I've set as a test, but I'm unsure how to check with a random letter because I don't know what the letter will be if that makes sense?

Comment: Its good if you post what have you tried?

Comment: @jackjay if((c>= 'a' && c<= 'z') || (c>= 'A' && c<= 'Z'))
{
  System.out.println("Accepted");
}
else
{
  System.out.println("Declined");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on K. Rzepeckas answer:

```
// generate your random string
Random r = new Random();
String s = String.valueOf((char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a')); // generate random char a-z

// test if the user input is equal to your random string
Scanner sc = new Scanner((System.in));
String character = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println((character.equals(s) ? "Correct": "Incorrect");
```

EDIT (with your random function from your comment):

```
// generate your random string
String s = String.valueOf(generateRandomChars("abcdefghijklmnopqrst‌​uvwxyz", 1));

// test if the user input is equal to your random string
Scanner sc = new Scanner((System.in));
String character = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println((character.equals(s) ? "Correct": "Incorrect");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test it using if/else or writing conditional phrase:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner((System.in));
char character = sc.next().charAt(0);
char temp;
Random rand = new Random();
System.out.println((temp = (char)('a' + rand.nextInt(26)))==character ? "Correct": "Incorrect, letter is: " + temp);
```

Comment: But the letter could be a-z it's not just h and p they were just examples.

Comment: It's basically this --      System.out.println(generateRandomChars("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 1)); -- this then generates 1 letter above at random, but the trouble is I can't predict what it is going to be to let it be correct or incorrect.

Comment: Is this now what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct you want to check if the user enter the same letter that was random, then try this code:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(25); // since index starts with 0
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";
    char aChar = abc.charAt(randomNumber);
    String myLetter = Character.toString(aChar);
    // System.out.println(myLetter ); // so you could check the letter 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number: ")
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    if(input.equals(myLetter)){
      System.out.println("Right" );
     }
    else{
         System.out.println("Wrong"); 
     }
```